# Notifications in Blazor - C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, timer, blazor-server-side

I have the next situation:

I have a project build it in Blazor Web Server, and is connected to a SQL Server. In the database I have a table to consult every day, to search if one of the rows datetime value has expire. If the value has expire, the system display an alert to the user.

I want to notify to the user, to do this, I installed the nuget package [blazored toast](https://github.com/Blazored/Toast), to display the notification. (this part is working)

But I don't know how I can create a timer o something similar to consult every day to the Db and show the correspond notification.

Answer (score 1):

I see at least two possibilities:

- Create a Hosted service that runs every day (ex: Midnight) and checks
  for what you want, and then sets some data in the database saying to
  display the Toast. Your code must check this value to know when to display  the Toast. When the Toast has been displayed, set back the
  value to default.
- Add a column in the database storing a date. If the date is not today's date, go check what you need in the database to know if you need to display a Toast. After that, set the date in the DB to the current date.